# Joining 2 list of different size in Python

Tags: python

I get "list of index out of range" error when try to use 2 different size list.

example:

```
ListA = [None, None, None, None, None]
ListB = ['A', None, 'B']

for x, y in enumerate(ListA):
    if ListB[x]:
        ListA[x]=ListB[x]
```

Doing this will get "list of index out of range" error, because ListB[3] and ListB[4] does not exist:
I hope to join ListA and ListB to get ListA look like this:

```
ListA = ['A', None, 'B', None, None]
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Note that in this particular case the result can be achieved with `listA = listB + listA[len(listB):]` or `listA[:len(listB)] = listB`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [itertools.izip_longest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest)

```
from itertools import izip_longest
ListA = [b or a for a, b in izip_longest(ListA,ListB)]
```

Answer (score 3):

The fastest solution is to use slice assignment

```
>>> ListA = [None, None, None, None, None]
>>> ListB = ['A', None, 'B']
>>> ListA[:len(ListB)] = ListB
>>> ListA
['A', None, 'B', None, None]
```

---

**Timing**

```
>>> def merge_AO(ListA, ListB):
    return [ i[1] for i in map(None,ListA,ListB)]

>>> def merge_ke(ListA, ListB):
    for x in range(len(ListB)): #till end of b
        ListA[x]=ListB[x]
    return ListA

>>> def merge_JK(ListA, ListB):
    ListA = [b or a for a, b in izip_longest(ListA,ListB)]
    return ListA

>>> def merge_AB(ListA, ListB):
    ListA[:len(ListB)] = ListB
    return ListA

>>> funcs = ["merge_{}".format(e) for e in ["AO","ke","JK","AB"]]
>>> _setup = "from __main__ import izip_longest, ListA, ListB, {}"
>>> tit = [(timeit.Timer(stmt=f + "(ListA, ListB)", setup = _setup.format(f)), f) for f in funcs]
>>> for t, foo in tit:
    "{} took {} secs".format(t.timeit(100000), foo)


'0.259869612113 took merge_AO secs'
'0.115819095634 took merge_ke secs'
'0.204675467452 took merge_JK secs'
'0.0318886645255 took merge_AB secs'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
>>> [i[1] for i in map(None,ListA,ListB)]
['A', None, 'B', None, None]
```

Comment: I believe that this fails on python3.x (unfortunately) as the behavior of `map` with multiple iterables changed -- Notably on python2.x, `map` uses the longer of the iterables and pads the other with `None`, whereas on python3.x, `map` uses the shorter of the two iterables.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
ListA = [None, None, None, None, None]
ListB = ['A', None, 'B']

for x in range(len(ListB)): #till end of b
    ListA[x]=ListB[x]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use MAP to avoid list index out of range error

```
for iterator,tup in enumerate(map(None,ListA,ListB)):
    if tup[1]:
        ListA[iterator] = tup[1]
```

This will fix the issue.